# A number with different remainders for given set of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How to find a number which gives different remainders on division by given set of prime numbers?
e. g. 
for a set {2, 3, 7}, 17 is a number which gives 3 different remainders 1, 2, 3 when divided by 2, 3, 7 respectively.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to find a way by taking number of examples, but, didn't find any conclusion.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: I thought of it only at first, but didn't found any way to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every set of primes, the product of the primes minus one does the job. The residue modulo every prime $p$ in the set is then $p-1$, hence the remainders are distinct.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of that.

Comment: Well, the required number is a big one wrt the primes. Is there someway or algorithm to find a number bigger than the biggest prime which satisfies these conditions.  This is in context with this interesting problem. https://www.codechef.com/JULY19B/problems/GUESSPRM

Comment: ** New Comment **                Well, the required number is a big one wrt the primes and is not a perfect square necessarily. Is there someway or algorithm to find a number bigger than the biggest prime which satisfies these conditions that it's square is unique modulo some prime p1,p2,p3..... pn.  This is in context with this interesting problem. https://www.codechef.com/JULY19B/problems/GUESSPRM                                             Should I ask a question again?

Comment: @SarthakRout The chinese remainder theorem guarantees that infinite many numbers satisfy the conditions. If you have a solution, add an arbitary multiple of the product of the primes to get another solution. You can make the number as big as you want.

Comment: I want to make the number as small as I want. And I should have an algorithm, if possible, to get smallest of those numbers.